# Can I play across platforms?

Tags: ios, android, tiny-tower

I got Tiny Tower for Android thinking I'd be able to continue my tower I started in iOS. But I don't see any option and I don't think I have an online account linked to my tower.

Is there any way to play my tower cross-platform or can I not do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, the game does not run cross-platform.

On iOS, if you have a Game Center account, your game is tied to it, which is why you can get your Tiny Tower game on multiple iOS devices. Obviously, you do not have Game Center on an Android device, so you won't have access to your game.

Comment: This is what I feared